# Can I tell Typescript to prefer types from webpack to @types/webpack?

Tags: typescript, webpack

Some of my Webpack plugins depend on `@types/webpack` 4.x, but I use Webpack 5.88, which already has types. And it seems Typescript resolves Webpack types to `@types/webpack`. As a workaround I added `"@types/webpack": "^5.28.0"` (the last version) to `resolutions`, but this doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a weird trick, but it works:

1. Add `"@types/webpack": "file:node_modules/webpack"` to both `devDependencies` and `resolutions` (we're using Yarn 1, NPM or other Yarn versions may need something different).
2. Remove `node_modules/@types/webpack` if it exists and run `yarn install`.
3. The above worked locally, but on CI I got `error Package "" refers to a non-existing file '".../node_modules/webpack"'`. This was fixed by adding `mkdir -p node_modules/webpack` to the preinstall script.